# Python - ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'tensorflow.keras.models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tried the following code below. Tried uninstalling/ installing tensorflow and changing to from tensorflow rather than import. And using a previous version of tensorflow.

````
# Import packages and print version
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

#Libraries for vectorisation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV




ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5764/3752405166.py in <module>
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import pandas as pd
----> 6 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
      7 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
      8 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D





ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'tensorflow.keras.models' (C:\Users\liamd\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\models\__init__.py)```
````

Comment: Input is not in keras.models but in keras.layers

Answer (score 0):

Input is not from the model API but is defined as [tensorflow.keras.Input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input)

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential,Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Input
```

Alternativley, you could use the InputLayer() from [tensorflow.keras.layers.InputLayer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer) and import it as:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer
```